# How to unzip image folder in colab

Tags: python, deep-learning, zip, google-colaboratory

I want to train a deep learning model on a Devanagari dataset containing around 9000 images. Since the dataset is huge, I want to use Google colab since it's GPU supported. I uploaded a folder from my local machine to Colab in Zip format. But an error occurred while unzipping the file.

```
from google.colab import files    
uploaded = files.upload()
   
for fn in uploaded.keys():
   print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

I try to zip files using `unzip devanagari-character-dataset.zip` but it throws the following error.

```
File "<ipython-input-8-92b289004693>", line 1
unzip devanagari-character-dataset.zip
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to solve the above issue.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)
```

Comment: Please add some explanations into your answer

Comment: The answer is straight forward and in understandable way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming python for that part

```
unzip "devanagari-character-dataset.zip"
```

not

```
unzip devanagari-character-dataset.zip
```

Perhaps wrap it in quotes if you want it to be serviced by things installed with pip
(then see @Vaibhav's answer)

OR: possibly precede it with a ! to make it a command (if you want the backend to service it like a regular command line serviced by things installed with apt)

like

```
!unzip devanagari-character-dataset.zip
```